# Type ' ' is not assignable to type ''.ts(2322) ANOTHA ONE

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm new and learning typescript, currently - enums, and somehow this example throw me an error, i don't understand why. Here's a code:

```
enum IStatus {
    SUCCESS = 'success',
    FAILED = 'failed'
}

interface ResponseSuccess {
    databaseId: number
    sum: number
    from: number
    to: number
}

interface ResponseFail {
    errorMessage: string
    errorCode: number
}

interface GoodResponse {
    status: IStatus.SUCCESS
    data: ResponseSuccess
}

interface BadResponse {
    status: IStatus.FAILED
    data: ResponseFail
}

let data: GoodResponse = {
    "status": 'success',  // error Type '"success"' is not assignable to type 'IStatus.SUCCESS'.ts(2322)
    "data": {
        "databaseId": 567,
        "sum": 10000,
        "from": 2,
        "to": 4
    }
}

let data2: BadResponse = {
    'status': "failed", // same error
    "data": {
        "errorMessage": "Error",
        "errorCode": 4
    }
}
```

i can use objects to describe my type like this and it works fine:

```
const Status = {
    success: 'success',
    failed: 'failed',
} as const

export type StatusType = keyof typeof Status
```

But I want to have a option to choose between "good" and "bad" status types.

Comment: …why aren’t you using the enum members?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `'success'` just only `literal String` and `IStatus.FAILED` is enum `has value` is `success`, but it's type still is enum. See more at [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

In your case, you should use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content).

```
interface Response<T extend ResponseSuccess | ResponseFail > {
  status: IStatus;
  data: T
}

let data: Response<ResponseSuccess> = {
  "status": IStatus.SUCCESS, // if 'status' is literal string try cast type: 'success' as IStatus.SUCCESS
  "data": {
    "databaseId": 567,
    "sum": 10000,
    "from": 2,
    "to": 4
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't change data and data2, imagine like I get it as promise and I must describe it with typescript. I don't bother about generics for now, coz it doesn't affect the error